# Is it possible to turn off the screen (just like pressing the power button) on android

Tags: android

Can you please tell me if it is possible to turn off the screen on android phone programmatically? So that it won't respond to any touch screen events but the application is still running?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question may be answered in the following Stack Overflow question.

[Calling hidden API in android to turn screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875669/calling-hidden-api-in-android-to-turn-screen-off)