# turn the screen on/off in Android with a shake

Tags: android, sensors, brightness

I'm making an app that needs to toggle the screen on/off when the user shakes the phone. So far, I've got a SensorEventListener that listens to the shakes as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317428/android-i-want-to-shake-it).

When I detect a shake, I change the value of the screen's brightness as suggested in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875669/calling-hidden-api-in-android-to-turn-screen-off). It all works great if I don't actually turn the screen off... if I set the brightness to 0.01f through the `public void setBright(float value)` method it works perfectly. However, if I set the brightness to 0.0f, the phone won't turn the screen again... not until I press the power button, at least.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? what am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

Thanks to [Dre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23033/dre) and [icyerasor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314089/icyerasor) I've looked further into the issue. I acquire a [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) before I set the brightness to 0.0f, but it still doesn't turn on when I shake the phone. However, when I debug the app I see that the setBright(1.0f) gets called allright when I shake the phone with the screen turned off; My suspicion is that the lockscreen is somehow messing with it, since it kicks in when I press the power button. After I press the power button, the app continues to work as it usually does. Is there a way to bypass the lockscreen?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you succeded in this requirement ?

Comment: Sorry, my requirements changed and it was no longer an issue for my project. My last was my best guess: if you deactivate the lockscreen, it would probably work.

Comment: I am having the similar problem as yours. But I want to know that how you are detecting the shake event of the device when the screen is off.

Comment: I haven't looked into this for a long time now, but as I recall it, I simply used a SensorEventListener and followed the suggestions provided in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: Setting it to brighnes 0.0 might also put the phone in sleep mode?

When you want to turn it on again programmatically, try acquiring a ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP Wakelock:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)mContext.getSystemService(
                                          Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                                      PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                                      | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                                      TAG);
wl.acquire(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with icyerasor's guess, however -- If the guess is correct and the phone is going to sleep you will have to acquire a [`PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to keep the CPU awake **before** you set the brightness to 0.0

I would test this before answering but I don't have access to an Android device at this moment.

Comment: I would even recommend a SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK. The ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP is only an additional modfier. And is ignored when using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK(at least the doc you link says that. Oh just saw that i copied the code without modyfing the flags.. editing.

Comment: Yeah, but holding a `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` then trying to set the brightness to 0 will probably fail, the problem is the CPU is probably going to sleep and the OP's code stops running.  They need to hold the `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to keep the CPU awake and their code running.

Comment: Ah okay. Then he should .acquire(), setBrightnesTo100(); .release(), right?

Comment: thanks! I did what you guys suggested, but it still doesn't work. I edited the question with more info, if that helps :)