# Turn on screen on device

Tags: android, android-intent, screen, broadcast

How can I turn the sceen on ?

I tried something like this

```
adb -d  shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

It really should work, I send broadcast intent it is received by the system, but the screen doesn't turn on

I do not understand what is the problem, is it possible to turn the screen of the device by code  ? I mean with software ? Cause it seems like the turning on of the screen is done just by the hardware button press . . . at least I got that felling , am I wrong ?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this one if i'm not mistaken : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891337/turning-on-screen-programmatically

Comment: Just for reference: if you use `adb shell am start -n packagename/activityname` to launch an app via adb, the screen will be turned on automatically if it's currently off (Tested on Android 5.0 with a Unity3d app)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650552/3806413

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could be wrong about this, but...

You shouldn't think of broadcasts as something to **send to get things done**, but instead think of them as things that are **sent when things are done**.

I think the system sends 'android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON' when screen is goes on, but sending 'android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON' does not necessarily make the screen go on.

I hope this makes sense.

For the answer, you can find it in...

- [Calling hidden API in android to turn screen off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875669/calling-hidden-api-in-android-to-turn-screen-off)
- [turn the screen on/off in Android with a shake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214033/turn-the-screen-on-off-in-android-with-a-shake)

Answer (score 33):

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER
```

Works to turn on screen (when display is off)
Works to turn off screen (when display is on/awake)

Comment: Hi, with turn off/on, it works on one device (android kitkat), but not on another one (wear marshmellow)

Comment: Works on both Marshmallow (6.0) and Jellybean (4.2.2) for me.

Comment: Works on Android 9.

Answer (score 24):

For Android 5.0 and above:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP
```

or

```
adb shell input keyevent 224
```

> ###### [KEYCODE_WAKEUP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_WAKEUP)
>
> Key code constant: Wakeup key. Wakes up the device. Behaves somewhat like `KEYCODE_POWER` but it has no effect if the device is already awake.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_WAKEUP

---

<sup>*Note: `KEYCODE_POWER` has been added in API level 1, while `KEYCODE_WAKEUP` has been added in API level 20!*</sup>

Answer (score 14):

u can turn it on/off if u do like:

```
adb shell
@shell: input keyevent 26
@shell: (enter or via hidden command empty line)
@shell: exit
```

this worked for me on some android versions ;)
(NOTE: this will turn the screen on and off, depends on the actual screen state)

To detect the current state of the screen u can use the following ways:
Android < 5.x.x
`adb shell dumpsys input_method`
In the output search for `mScreenOn=true/false`

Android >= 5.x.x
`adb shell dumpsys display`
In the output search for `mScreenState=ON/OFF`

In my scripts i use this `\s{0,}mScreen(State|On)=(?<STATE>(true|false|on|off))\s{0,}` (Compiled|IgnoreCase|ExplicitCapture) regular expression for both outputs to detect the current state.

EDIT (16.03.2018):

There is also another way to detect the screen state, it works since Android 3.0. The `dumpsys window policy` command will give us all we need. - In the output search for `mScreenOn(Fully)?=(?<STATE>(true|false))`.
There are also other useful informations like:

- `mUnrestrictedScreen` (value is like: `(0,0) 768x1280`)
- `mRestrictedScreen` (value is like: `(0,0) 768x1184`)

Regards,

k1ll3r8e

Answer (score 2):

The command to toggle the screen on/off is:

```
adb shell input keyevent 26
```

This condensed command is preferred because it allows you to use it in scripts.

Cheers!

Comment: Toggle ist not equal "turn on", turn on must take into account if the display is already on or not, otherwise it may be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

this works in android 12

```
#!/bin/bash
screenState=$(adb shell dumpsys window policy | grep screenState=SCREEN_STATE_ | cut -c 32-)

if [ "$screenState" == "OFF" ]; then 
    adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER

fi
```