# Remotely turning on display and opening Apps

Tags: android

I have a tablet connected to my home automation system. I would like my tablet to open an app when specific conditions are met.

My idea was to install some sort of SSH server on the tablet. When my server wants the tablet to open the App, it logins into the tablet and executes a command turn on the display and open the App.

In theory this works but I haven't been able to find any documentation on the web on how to do this.

I've got as far as installing SSHDroid however when the tablet locks, the SSH disconnects. I'm also unable to find any commands which turn on the display and open apps.

Comment: You can use `adb` over wireless, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/1283715) for how to connect a device over network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From a computer, if you have USB access already (no root required)**, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/1283715) more details.

- Connect your tablet with computer(has `adb` installed) and run

  ```
  adb tcpip 5555
  ```
- Then you can control your tablet over wifi by run

  ```
  adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555 // you can use port forward in you gateway to enable you connect over internet.
  ```
- Now after connected with tablet you are able to use `adb shell` commands.

[**Turn Screen On**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468362/1283715)

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER
```

[**Start an Application**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567928/1283715)

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```