# Android: Turn off screen from a service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, screen

I am trying to figure out how to turn off the screen from within a service. I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875669/calling-hidden-api-in-android-to-turn-screen-off) but I am failing to realize how to do this from within a service. I don't really want to deal with wake locks because as soon as the screen goes off, I don't really care about turning it back via java code. I just need a one time method for turning the screen off and I have searched forever on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

(1) Create a dummy `Activity` and use it to get a `Window` object through the `getWindow();` method. Then you would use an `Intent` to call the screen off from your `Service`.

(2) Use `IHardwareService.Stub`. Not part of the SDK, but there's a workaround in this blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20210224163252/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html

**BTW: I would strongly recommend the first option. You never know when a class that is not part of the SDK might change.**

Comment: By dummy activity, do you mean just create an activity and don't inflate with XML? Is that possible?

Comment: @Semper yes. But thinking it better, if you only care to turn off the screen, a completely black activity should do the same trick. That is, of course, unless you want to turn off the *device*, but that's another issue.

Comment: I'll look into it tomorrow and get back with you on this. Whowoudaevarthunk...black activity :)

Comment: So, I got it working. I created a transparent activity and scaled the brightness down to 0 in 3 seconds since that is the fastest timeout you can set. Is there any way to overcome this without having to be signed as a system app? It technically works, but I need instant off, not a fadeout in 3 seconds. 3 seconds is just a tad bit too long.

Comment: is it possible to wake the screen up using the above approach?

Comment: Actually the second approach (IHardwareService) is not resultful in Android 2.2+.
So the 1st way is recommended.