# dismiss the keyguard in a Service?

Tags: java, android, service, android-emulator, android-widget

how to dismiss the keyguard in a Service?

Flag.Dismiss.keyguard cannot be use as there is no window - am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. You have to either send a call back message to an activity to get the window or apply a dummy activity. Answer to your question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538923/keyguardmanager-flag-dismiss-keyguard-for-service)