# Turn off screen immediately not dim Android

Tags: android, screen

Just to clarify, I KNOW there are ways to DIM the screen but I don't want to do that. I want to simulate a screen timeout but immediately... not using:

```
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System
                .SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, DimScreenValue, 0);
```

or

```
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, iTimerScreenTimeout);
```

If possible, I want to avoid using Administrative options (screenLockNow)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2046576/794088  might help.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure this is only dimming.